# Asynchronous call(async/await pattern) messes up Z-ordering of Xamarin Android widgets

Tags: c#, android, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm working with on the UI of a Xamarin Android app and I am running into some issues with the Z ordering of the widgets due to delay caused by an asynchronous call. I have 2 classes StandardItemView and CustomStandardItemView, CustomStandardItemView inherits from StandardItemView.

```
class ItemView : RelativeLayout
{
    Context context;
    Item item;  
    public ItemView(Context context, Item item)
    :base(context)
    {
        this.item = item;
        this.context = context;
        createView(item)
        //do some event handling stuff
    }

    private async void createView(Item item)
    {
        //make async call for image
        var image = await ImageService.getImageAsync(item.imageURL);

        //create image View and add to relative layout
        //hacky workaround
         if (GetChildAt(0) != null)//if the customTextView has already been added bring it to front so it's not covered by image
            {
                this.BringChildToFront(GetChildAt(0));
            }
     //create textview and add on top of imageView
    }
}
```

ItemView creates a widget with an imageView and a textView placed on top of it, however the image used for the imageView is an online resource and as such an asynchronous call is made using the async/await pattern, when the asynchronous call returns the imageView is laid out and the textview is placed on it.

```
class CustomItemView:ItemView
{
    public CustomItemView(Context context, Item item)
    :base(context, item)
    {
        //create and add customTextView
    }
}
```

The CustomItemView however as an extra textview(the customTextView), so the CustomItemView on initialization calls the base constructor which tries to layout the ItemView widgets but while waiting for the aynchronous call to get the online image, control is returned to the CustomItemView constructor which then draws the customTextView widget. The end result is a view with its widgets out of order, the customTextView is behind the ImageView instead of being in front of it. I previously went around this by putting a "hacky" solution in the ItemView creatview method, I check if the customTextView has already been added and then call the BringChildToFront method to place it in front of the image but I foresee this causing problems if further widgets are added to the CustomItemView. Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: 1. Using await in constructor is not very good idea. You can not make constructor async, so what is the point? 2. You don't wait, so your "do some event handling stuff" will be called before createView ACTUALLY completes.

Comment: @YuriS Thanks, I understand. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: Without having the whole code I cannot recommend much. I don't know if you are using any MVVM patterns and where your Items are used. So if you want to send me the code I can run I can fix it for you (let me know and I will provide my email or you put it somewhere I can grab). Meantime one suggestion: You can add image placeholder to layout before actual image is loaded. Then just assign loaded image to placeholder.
BUT this is just workaround. I still think you should change async call in constructor. When I have a code I can see what are options for that.

Comment: I believe that what Yuri is saying is correct. By whatever means you choose, you will have to make sure that your image view is created and added before the text views are added, or use the workaround you are using my by sending the image view to the back (or bringing the text views to the front).

Comment: Your biggest culprit here is an `async void` method. Next to that you are invoking it inside your constructor and it will fire and forget. You should really change the return type from `void` to `Task` unless it's an event handler. https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async If there's a need to re-order the view, make sure to call `Invalidate()` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Drawing - Order of drawing is most important here.